# Is information being destroyed in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, unitarity

If some information is encoded on n electrons (n-qubits) and m electrons are annihilated by interaction with positrons, then only n-m qubits remain and only the information on them can be accessed. So what happens to the information encoded on the m qubits that were destroyed. And if the photons formed does carry the information, then is new information being created?

Comment: Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hiding_theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an electron and a positron annihilate, they don’t just disappear. There will be other stuff coming out of the reaction. The quantum state of the fields after the annihilation will contain the information of the electron and positron.

In general, unitary evolution preserves information.